Is there a way disable browsing history in Microsoft Edge?
Microsoft Edge Version 131.0.2903.112 (Official build) (64-bit)
Is there a switch to disable browsing history in Microsoft Edge? I see how to delete history and the ability to delete it when the browser closes, but not a way to prevent saving the URLs while you are using it.
I looked through settings and privacy but I don't see a switch to disable browser history without closing the browser.

Does Enable or Disable Saving History in Microsoft Edge in Windows 10 | Tutorials answer your question?
